# why no += operator for vectors in stl

Tags: c++, stl

I am curious? What high fundu logic goes behind not implementing:

```
result+=vector1;
```

where both result and vector1 are stl vectors.

Note: i know how to implement that bit, but i need to know what logic, the sages who designed STL were using when they chose not to implement this feature?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What are you expecting `result` to contain, the result of concatenating the original `result` with `vector1` or an element-wise `+=` (whatever that means for the underlying types), possibly default-initializing members if the sizes don't match?

And yes, this is an answer ;) .

Operator overloading should only be used where the meaning of the operation is unambiguous and practical for the underlying type and where it would offer a significant notational brevity over appropriately named function calls.

Note that `valarray` has more operator overloads than `vector` due to its interface and intended use.

Comment: This can be a gotcha when using Python and Numpy, for example. In python, the + operator concatenates lists, but it is an element-wise addition in numpy arrays.

Comment: I wish more languages took the approach of making addition and concatenation separate operators.

Answer (score 3):

I think the operator is not overloaded because its meaning is ambiguous. Do you mean to append the vectors? `result.insert( result.end(), vector1.begin(), vector1.end() )` accomplishes that.

Comment: yeouch. that isn't the only way, is it? `vec1.append(vec2)` would be pretty unambiguous, but much more friendly.

Comment: For your toolbox: `template<typename C1, typename C2> void append(C1& c1, C2 const& c2) { c1.insert(c1.end(), c2.begin(), c2.end()); }`. Not every possible function is in the STL, and quite a few trivial functions are missing in favor of more complex functions.

Answer (score 2):

My take on things (based, in large part on *[Elements of Programming](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/book.html)*) is that Stepanov considers containers as substantially less important than algorithms and iterators. From his viewpoint, the algorithms are the most important part. Iterators are secondary, and containers are simply the storage necessary for iterators to do their job.

In the book, he starts off with some basics like objects and transformations. Chapter six is devoted primarily to iterators (in fact, "Iterators" is the name of the chapter). That also has nearly the only mention of containers in the book:

> There are four kinds of linear
>   traversal: single-pass forward (an
>   input stream), multipass forward (a
>   singly linked list), bidirectional (a
>   doubly linked list), and random access
>   (an array).

The only other place I remember him mentioning containers at all is to point out that a particular type (a "linearizable") isn't a container because it doesn't own its contents.

There are also some other arguments to be made, such as minimizing duplication and avoiding ambiguity, but personally I think they're secondary (at best). The STL attempts to generalize algorithms to the greatest possible degree. Containers are de-emphasized, and a large part of the point of iterators is (or at least to me seems to be) to ensure that they stay in the background.

Comment: I dont get it! My understanding was that Abstractions are more important in C++ than implementations, then why does STL focuses so much on implementations, i.e. different types of algorithms, rather than abstractions such as containers. I can live without a count_if function, but a keyset function for STL Maps is something of more help.

Comment: One of the stark difference between C++ and Python/JAVA is that data structures such as lists, and hashmaps are extremely easier to handle in later.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost.Assignment library does, in fact, add a `+=` operator to `std::vector` and other containers.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html